# Looking for this movie involving treasure

Tags: identify-this-movie

I think it was pirate treasure. Ok, here are the plot points that I can remember or vaguely remember

1. The film was made in the 1990's (or maybe very early 2000's), I am not sure though if it was for theater's or just a TV movie (though I did watch it on TV). It was english and made, I think, in the US.
2. The protagonists I think were teens or very young adults. I'm not sure how many were there, but I remember two of them being a boy (I think he's the main lead) and a girl
3. They are looking for pirate treasure I think
4. At one point, our heroes go to this family. The family consists of a father (who has a beard), a pudgy looking mother and a teen daughter/young adult named Angel.
5. The father then attacks protagonists (perhaps when they mention their quest to find the treasure). One scene during the fight is when the father or the protagonists fling over dishes over the table and break (causing the mother to shout "MY DISHES !").
6. The protagonists eventually find the treasure (I think on an island), but the family arrives and takes the treasure from them.
7. One scene has the family sailing away on their boat, in which Angel asks the father if they are going to be rich. I don't remember what they say after that
8. The protagonists then go after the familys boat, and first dispose of angel, then the father (I think they dispose of the father after they board the boat).
9. The mother then arrives with a cutlass/saber sword, growling that they killed her family. The boy fights with the mother, and eventually throws her overboard, into the sea. She temporarily reappears, now with her part of her face deformed and with a distorted voice, shouting at the protagonists to help her, before finally submerging into the water and drowning.

If any of the plot points are familiar with you and match the movie that I'm looking for, please tell. Thank you =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Lost Treasure of Sawtooth Island](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0228968/combined) from 1999 with Ernest Borgnine.

> Danny Quinn (Seth Bernard) lives with one great dream... he wants to prove his late father was right about a pirate treasure in the depths of Lake Michigan. [...]
>
> Danny sets off on his great quest, taking a ragtag crew which includes Toby Weems (Mike Kelly), a windy old town character, Rufe (Logan Lipton), Danny's oddball buddy, and Smokey Jeanne (Brennan Hesser), a tough Chicago girl. They sail off pursued by treasure hunter Doc Biehler and his weird wife Mother. After a knock-down battle with Doc, who makes off with the treasure map, it's Smokey's toughness and support that wins Danny over.

Pretty sure the villains have a daughter who's called Angel. Here's the scene where Mother is defeated and half of her face is deformed after she falls overboard because she's really a one-eyed banshee(!):